# datagridview show specific columns in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a table called Books(BookId,BookName,Amount,Publisher), and a dataGridView1 in a form.
I want that the dataGridView1 will show only the columns "BookName" and "Amount".
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `AutoGeneratedColumns` property to `false` before assigning ItemsSource to datagridview